How can I get last three values from array of objects
I have an array of object with a few values. I would like to get only last, three values (ownerSurname, color and bark).
I tried to use slice or length but with failure.
const myValues: MyValues<string>[] = [
   {
    name: "Lucky",
    surname: "Luck",
    age: "3",
    breed: "Shepherd",
    owner: "Paul",
    ownerSurname: "Luck",
    color: "Brown",
    bark: "All the time",
  },
]

const newData = myValues.slice(-3)
<MyComponent value={newData}/>


That should be throwing some errors in TypeScript, because what is shown is not an array of strings; it's an array of a single object.

Do you want the last three elements in an array?  Or do you want an array of objects which are a subset of the properties of the objects in your original array?  It's not really clear from the attempt.  (This seems to have less to do with TypeScript or React and more to do with simply objects and arrays in JavaScript, and generally understanding your own data structure...)

Actually, I was mistaken. There are no TypeScript errors, because we don't know what MyValues is.

My data is an array that has only one object whose values I need to extract (only the last three).

@Emm: Is the array always exactly of length 1?  Can you define "the last three" in this case?  Are they specific properties you want, or are you expecting objects to internally store properties in some specific sort order?

@David Yes, the array is always exactly of length 1. These are the specific ones I need. The last three, they will not be reordered or modified in any way.

Why not just get [myValues[0].ownerSurname, myValues[0].color, myValues[0].bark] then?

@Emm: So then do you just want something like this?: value={newData.map(({ ownerSurname, color, bark }) => ({ ownerSurname, color, bark }))}  This would assign to that value prop a new array consisting of the same number of objects in the original array, but the new objects contain only those three specific properties.  (Untested/freehand code, but the idea is to simply .map over the array and destructure the three properties you want, returning those properties in a new object.)

Object.entries(myValues[0]).slice(-3) should do the trick. mdn object.entries

@David Object destructuring works, thanks!

This is more related to simple Javascript rather than React.
If you really would like to know, first you need to "get" the object itself, in this case because is an array with one single element it is only a matter of select the [0] index.
const myValues: MyValues<string>[] = [
   {
    name: "Lucky",
    surname: "Luck",
    age: "3",
    breed: "Shepherd",
    owner: "Paul",
    ownerSurname: "Luck",
    color: "Brown",
    bark: "All the time",
  },
]

const obj = myValues[0];

const newObj = { 
  ownerSurname: obj.ownerSurname, 
  bark: obj.bark, 
  color: obj.color 
};

<MyComponent value={newObj}/>

These are basic functions of javascript and are not related to React.
Perhaps you need to find more basic lessons on how objects and arrays work in Javascript.

I can only guess what you actually want to achieve, so ill provide some different solutions.
The thing i think you want to do is, only get the values "ownerSurname", "color" and "bark" for each of your objects in your array. That could be achieved like this:
[{name: "name", age: 20}].map(value => ({name: value.name}))

As explanation: This code maps through every object, and then returns a new object with only the "name" field in it. You could change this code to your specific example.
I can also imagine, that you might want to omit all other values from only one object. This might be a misunderstanding when coming from other languages like phps where objects are handled with brackets.
You could just do that by removing the brackets from your "myValues" like this:
const myObject = {name: "name", age: 19}
const myNewObject = {name: myObject.name}

Please note that slice takes the last 3 values of an array, not an object. Please see the difference here: https://medium.com/@zac_heisey/objects-vs-arrays-42601ff79421

Thank you. It means that I have an array of objects and I would like to work on the data of this array it refers to the objects so I should using methods for objects instead of arrays right?

yes you're right! First of all you need to get your object from the array though.
